# How to save the state of an activity? All information is lost when the app is closed

Tags: android, kotlin

I need my app to save the state of images and future text fields so that when the user closes out of the app or even restarts their phone, the data is still there. It's kind of a diary.

```
class stageOne1 : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var manifestImage: ImageView
companion object {
    const val IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 100
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_stage_one1)

    manifestImage = findViewById(R.id.manifestImage)
    manifestImage.setOnClickListener{
        pickImageGallery()
    }
}

private fun pickImageGallery(){
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
    intent.type = "image/*"
    startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE)
}
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        manifestImage.setImageURI(data?.data)
    }
}

override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
}

override fun onRestoreInstanceState(
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    persistentState: PersistableBundle?
) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState, persistentState)
}
```

}

Let me know if you need to look at my XML.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Let me know if you need to look at my XML.` curious to know why you think this has something to do with xml ? if you are completely new to android development, there are some nice [codelabs](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view#0) you can look at

Comment: there's also https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage

Comment: You should remember the url of the picked image (put it in shared preferences as suggested) then you can use the url at new start to directly feed the image view.

Answer (score 0):

you can use shared preferences which will help you to save state of your app on closing as well as restarting the phone but make sure if you delete the data of the app or uninstall it then its data will be lost.

sharedPreferences are done in this way to store

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("login_prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                                editor.putBoolean("isLoggedIn", true);
                                editor.apply();
```

here instead of putBoolean you can have string value also

here is the way to retrive it

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("login_prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean isLoggedIn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isLoggedIn",false);
```

by using it make sure that the hierarchy or flow of your app is sequence wise otherwise you will face error

Comment: OP has the kotlin tag on their question

Comment: but you can apply shared prefrences on any languange

Comment: sure. but if OP is new, then they probably don't want to struggle with doing figuring out the difference between java and kotlin

Comment: I think it's a good answer. The Java does not matter. Using SharedPreferences does matter.

Comment: Yeah I've had a hard time finding any tuts that actually use an image. Everything else is directing me to firebase. Could you be a little more concise for a frustrated newbie?

Comment: I think a newbie -frustrated or not-  should not start with Firebase but with reading a lot of pages tagged `android`. You will find all as this is discussed regularly.